# Question of the Week #39

Tags: discussion, status-completed, superuser-blog, question-of-the-week

Now we're into post #39 of the "Top Question" of Super User in the [Super User blog](http://blog.superuser.com). Please post and vote for your favorite question for this week.

Please post any questions that you feel is of worth and the reason why.  Try not to promote your own questions or answers for publicity's sake. We are looking for questions that are of similar par to those selected in the [Super User Contest](https://meta.superuser.com/search?q=super+user+contest). If you like a posted question then vote it up. Each week we'll to try to post about a question and its contents.

When submitting a QotW, please indicate if you would be interested in writing about it for the blog. This is a factor which we take into consideration when selecting what to blog about - we need a post we can actually say something interesting about; it shouldn't be something we've written about too much before, and it helps to have somebody interested in writing the article.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Why are websites suddenly asking me about cookies?](https://superuser.com/q/454757/4377)

> I have for a long time known that websites give me cookies so that small pieces of information can be remembered about my habits, passwords etc. I accept this, but all of a sudden they are asking for my permission to do so.
>
> Why has this changed? What sparked this?

Comment: I really like the new law (sadly, it's only implemented in the EU), but is this question even on topic? It's not about hardware, software or networking, but it *is* about websites.

Comment: @Dennis the questions seems reasonable to me, because even though the answer is "websites", the question-asker would've had no way of knowing whether it was something on his computer or on the website causing it.

Answer (score 5):

[Is the Windows Experience Index calculation the same on Windows 7 and 8](https://superuser.com/questions/453848/4377)

> Is the Windows Experience Index score calculated the same way on Windows 7 and 8?

Comment: Would this give enough material to write about?

Comment: @slhck we could go into detail as to how WEI score is calculated

Comment: I'd be interested in doing some tests with identically configured VMs or something. I think a lot of the variation people are seeing is more due to different drivers than it is due to the new scoring system.